# UITableViewCell does not appear in my table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableVIew`. Now I made my own `UITableViewCell`. But if my table appears nothing is shown. However the cells are still selectable and open the `DetailView`. Which command have I forgotten?

```
//Customize the appearance of table view cells.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainTableCell";

    MainTableCell *cell = (MainTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cel lIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[[MainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDef ault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
    }

    // Configure the cell. 
    VerwaltungInformation *selectedFormel = [listOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.FormelNameLabel.text = selectedFormel.nameFormel;

    return cell; 
}
```

Do I have to add special things? If somebody needs more code - please tell me.

---

Here is my MainTableCell.h:

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MainTableCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *FormelNameLabel;
    UILabel *ErklaerungVerfuegbarLabel;
    UILabel *BeispielVerfuegbarLabel;
    UILabel *RechnerVerfuegbarLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *FormelNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *ErklaerungVerfuegbarLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *BeispielVerfuegbarLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *RechnerVerfuegbarLabel;`
@end
```

And here is my MainTableCell.m:

```
#import "MainTableCell.h"

@implementation MainTableCell
@synthesize FormelNameLabel;`
@synthesize ErklaerungVerfuegbarLabel;
@synthesize BeispielVerfuegbarLabel;
@synthesize RechnerVerfuegbarLabel;`

- (void)dealloc {
    [FormelNameLabel release];
    [ErklaerungVerfuegbarLabel release];
    [BeispielVerfuegbarLabel release];
    [RechnerVerfuegbarLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you connected properly the datasource and delegate of tableView? If yes, put a breakpoint in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section and take a look at return value (it must be a quantity of your rows)

Comment: The table works but if i add the cell i will get no signature on the tablecells. Do i have to declare the cellin the rootviecontroller.h or somewhere else? Because i have only imported the MainTableCell.h and did nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

you have commented this line

```
cell. VerwaltungInformation *selectedFormel = [listOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and also check wthr

```
selectedFormel.nameFormel
```

contains any value.

Comment: selectedFormel.nameFormel returns a string. But i dont know what you mean with the first part of your post...

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'll try to answer.
1.try to NSLog this value selectedFormel.nameFormel before setting it to the label.text.

```
NSLog(@"selectedFormel.nameFormel:%@", selectedFormel.nameFormel);
```

2.Have you configured your cell properly? are you sure that for example FormelNameLabel's frame is not zero?

```
NSLog(@"cellFrame:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
```

Are you sure that you have added a label to the cell as subview?
If all these things are done and it still shows nothing provide a code from your cell!

Comment: My consol : selectedFormel.nameFormel:PQ-Formel ; cellFrame:{{0, 0}, {320, 44}} - And now? Should i post my MainTableCell.h/.m?

Comment: Yes, I think you should post it